# regex for all urls in string not capturing urls with question mark

Tags: php, regex, url

I start with this PHP string.

```
$bodyString = '
    another 1 body
    reg http://www.regularurl.com/home
    secure https://facebook.com/anothergreat.
    a subdomain http://info.craig.org/
    dynamic; http://www.spring1.com/link.asp?id=100408
    www domain; at www.wideweb.com
    single no subdomain; simple.com';
```

Need to turn all domains, urls into anchor(`<a>`) elements.

`preg_replace('#[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]*)?#si', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $bodyString)`

`$bodyString` result:

```
'another 1 body
    reg <ahref="http://www.regularurl.com/home">http://www.regularurl.com/home</a>
    secure <a href="https://facebook.com/anothergreat.">https://facebook.com/anothergreat.</a>
    a subdomain <a href="http://info.craig.org/">http://info.craig.org/</a>
    dynamic; <a href="http://www.spring1.com/link.asp">http://www.spring1.com/link.asp</a>?id=100408
    www domain; at <a href="www.wideweb.com">www.wideweb.com</a>
    single no subdomain; <a href="simple.com">simple.com</a>';
```

Result: All urls, domains are turned into `<a>` **except** `http://www.spring1.com/link.asp?id=100408`

What is missing in the regex to make this work?

Comment: Maybe [this will help](https://regex101.com/r/CyTddx/1).

Comment: I think if you can write this much regex as in the question, you can find the solution yourself. Before copy pasting code from internet, please make sure to try it from your end and post your research as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$bodyString = '
    another 1 body
    reg http://www.regularurl.com/home
    secure https://facebook.com/anothergreat.
    a subdomain http://info.craig.org/
    dynamic; http://www.spring1.com/link.asp?id=100408
    www domain; at www.wideweb.com
    single no subdomain; simple.com';

$regex = '@(http)?(s)?(://)?(([a-zA-Z])([-\w]+\.)+([^\s\.]+[^\s]*)+[^,.\s])@'; 
$converted_string = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $bodyString);
echo $converted_string;
```

[**Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/88f00a94fc72d16c6f37740abaf7ea5c07d15530)

Regex Explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/XKBhpn/1)

Answer (score 1):

Building on @WiktorStribiżew's comment, you could try this:

```
[^\s]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(?:[?/][^\s]*)*
```

**[Trial over here](https://regex101.com/r/CyTddx/2)**

**Note -** Although there are already 2 answers as of now, this seems to be more concise, using `[^\s]`

## Explanation -

`[^\s]{2,256}` matches 2 to 256 characters which is the `https://facebook` and `https://www.randomdomain` part,
`\.` matches the dot after that,
`[a-z]{2,4}` is the domain extension eg: `com`, `in` etc.
`\b` is the word boundary,
`(?:[?/][^\s]*)*` is a non-capturing group which matches either a slash `/` or question mark `?` and more of the url, all of which can be repeated zero-or-more times, indicating the sub-pages of the URL.

To gain a better understanding of Regex Syntax, you should [try this website: rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)

Answer (score 0):

`[-\w@:%+.\~#?&/=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b[^\s]*`

`[^\s]*` will add any non-space character to the url. When there's a space its not a part of the URL. Simple and easy.

working url [here](https://regex101.com/r/1vjy61/1)